# Use Javascript to call login button on Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the api.signuporsignin content definition. I have to integrate with a custom 3rd party Identity Provider that does not implement OpenID Connect nor SAML. I can do all the protocol with Javascript but I need a way to call the login button after it succeeds. Is there a way from Javascript to call this login button and pass paremeters?

thanks in advance

regards

Guzmán

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how do you plan to integrate and display the identity provider?